# Searching if all properties exist in a list of entities using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I have the following entities:

```
[Table("Entities")]
public abstract class Entity { 
 public int EntityID { get; set; } 
 public string Description { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

And the Tag Entity:

```
public class Tag {
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }
}
```

As the above makes sort of clear Tags are **not** reused just stored as strings. This has made determining whether Entities share tags slightly more difficult (and slow).

I have a working search to return a list of entities in which the entities contain any of the tags:

```
List<string> searchTags = new List<String> {"test1", "test2"};
entities = (_entityRepository.Entities
            .Where(o=>o.Tags.Any(f=>searchTags.Contains(f.TagValue)));
```

Now I also need to return a list of Entities which contain all of the tags in the list. As a non-property variable cannot be passed into a Contains method I cannot just reverse the order of the call with an all, but this is basically what I am trying to achieve:

```
entities = (_entityRepository.Entities
            .Where(o=>o.Tags.All(f=>f.TagValue.Contains(searchTags)));
```

I think I have just hit the point where I need to correct the DB schema to re-use Tags which should provide a general performance benefit when filtering my entities on lists of Tags, but I still wanted to ask the following questions:

1. Am I over complicating this and is there a simple Linq statement which accomplishes this or,
2. Is this something for which I would should use predicate builder to set my criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
var query = _entityRepository.Entities.Select(e => e);
query = searchTags.Aggregate(query, (current, tag) => current.Where(e => e.Tags.Any(t => t.TagValue == tag)));
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I had to make some changes to my data model before I could fully test, but this seemed to accomplish what I was asking when I backed out my changes to test (I couldn't spend a lot of time at it). Thanks - helped me look up the right things to accomplish a few other tasks as well.

Comment: Glad it helped. Btw, to answer question 2 (a bit): did you know System.Linq.Dynamic exists? Nice to use if you want to dynamically build linq queries